# How to remove only text from a td?

Tags: jquery

This is the HTML of my `td`:

```
<td class="SmallCols PadOn">
    6 
    <input type="hidden" id="HiddenID" value="0" name="HiddenID">
</td>
```

`6` is the only text inside in the `td`. The `td` also has hidden field which I do not want to remove. I just want to remove the text which is `6`. I tried this code but no luck:

```
var cloneTr = $('#StudentGrid tr:last').clone();
cloneTr.closest('td').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove().end().end();
```

Looking for help and suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `closest()` goes up the DOM tree, whereas you need to go down the tree to find the child element, so should use `find()` instead. Also the `end()` calls are redundant. Try this:

```
var cloneTr = $('#StudentGrid tr:last').clone();
cloneTr.find('td').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/x49fx11c/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.